# Chutzpah Test Runner/ adapter for visual studio 2013 not picking up .ts tests , but running from the console.?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chutzpah

I am using Mocha Framework for typescript test cases. i am able to run the test cases from the chutzpah console. but visual studio test adapter/runner is not picking up the test cases. pleas guide... following is the Json.

```
>     "Framework": "mocha",
>     "MochaInterface": "bdd",
>     "RootReferencePathMode": "SettingsFileDirectory",
>     "EnableCodeCoverage": false,
>     "IgnoreResourceLoadingErrors": true,
>     "EnableTestFileBatching": false,
>     "TestFileTimeout": 30000,
```

Comment: Do you see any errors/warning on the tests or output window?

Comment: i just see , 0 run , 0 passed and 0 failed .... though i have more than 20 test cases...

Comment: And running the exact same test using chutzpah.console.exe work? Is your chutzpah.console.exe the same version as VS plugin?

Comment: yes both are same.... and another finding is . if for the same test i use jasmine .. then every thing works fine :(

Comment: If you turn on tracing do what do you see in the chutzpah.log file?

Comment: it reads each test file, but does nothing..

Comment: Can you provide a repro I can run locally?